# Find Lowest Value in Surrounding Cells in Grid

Tags: python, list

I'm currently working with a grid represented by a list comprehension in Python. I have starting cell, say at `grid[x][y]`.

Each coordinate has a certain value associated with it: `grid[x][y].val = 20`

I'd like to check all surrounding cells to see which one has a value lower than the initial cell and is the lowest of all surrounding cells.

I've thought about checking each cell manually `grid[x][y+1], grid[x+1][y], etc` with some if statements but I have a feeling there has to be a better way.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 2):

Typically you want to set up a list of pairs

```
deltas = [(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1),
          ( 0, -1),          ( 0, 1),
          ( 1, -1), ( 1, 0), ( 1, 1)]
```

and loop over it:

```
for dx, dy in deltas:
    grid[x + dx][y + dy]
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember to check for edge cases--if x==0, you don't want to check a non-existent cell to the left of x, for example.  This solution uses a generator expression for compact code and also checks boundaries:

```
def nearest_lowest(grid,x,y):
    deltas = [(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1),
              ( 0, -1),          ( 0, 1),
              ( 1, -1), ( 1, 0), ( 1, 1)]
    return min(grid[x+dx][y+dy].val for (dx, dy) in deltas \
            if 0 <= x+dx < 100 and 0 <= y+dy < 100)
```

Note that I am assuming there a 100x100 grid; alter the code as necessary (or add that as a variable).

Answer (score 0):

This function should do the trick:

```
def min_surround(grid, x, y):
    return min(grid[x+dx][y+dy].val for dx in range(-1, 2) for dy in range(-1, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the .val values are stored in a numpy array, then finding the minimum of a region is straightforward

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.normal(size=[6,6])
z = np.min(x[0:3,2:5])
print x
print z
```

which results in

```
[[-0.40201157  0.46485353  1.1052583   1.11755495 -1.83926315  1.52196255]
 [-1.33033205 -0.12079264  0.07514305 -0.54083923 -1.32646675 -0.678275  ]
 [-0.88322977  1.4105751   0.39753243 -0.89098143  0.95593871 -0.71951623]
 [ 0.49596028  0.21729938 -1.50148048  1.94903521  1.14637429 -1.10754165]
 [ 0.13870651 -2.10966853  0.4137035   0.3555691   0.36410423  0.3190395 ]
 [ 1.00280868  0.61461297 -2.23789591  0.54246954  2.03222197  1.05972663]]
-1.83926314797
```